# Simultaneous authorization of the administrator in the admin panel and on the site(Django)

Tags: python, django, authentication, authorization

When logging in through the admin panel, the administrator simultaneously logs in to the site and in the admin panel, how can I fix this, please tell me?
The problem is that when I go on behalf of the admin in the admin panel, authorization occurs on the site that I am developing, and I do not need it. I would like the authorization to be performed separately on the site(for users) and on the admin panel(for admin).(DJANGO).Please help me with this question ???

Comment: Would it be enough to block admins from being able to view the site while still only having one user logged in at a time? Or do you need to be able to have an admin logged in and a user logged in simultaneously?

Comment: It would be cool to be able to have administrator and user login at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's an easy way to do what you want to do. The idea of a single user being logged in at a time is pretty fundamental to how Django works.

If this is just to make development and testing easier (by not having to constantly switch users), this can be accomplished by using multiple browsers. For example, you can simultaneously log into with an administrator account in Firefox and with a standard user account in Chrome.

If you still need to do this for one browser, the most obvious way I can think of would be to implement two separate websites - one for your admin pages and one for your site. Here's one way you could implement a separate site for just your admin pages:

1. Create a file myproject/admin_settings.py

```
from myproject.settings import *

# make sure any cookies will be named differently
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'myproject_admin_csrftoken'
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'myproject_admin_sessionid'

# point to a different urls.py file
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.admin_urls'
```

2. Create a file myproject/admin_urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

3. Remove any references to the admin section from your other urls.py file.

Now you should be able to run just the admin site by itself:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=myproject.admin_settings
```

If you want to run both sites using Django dev server, open two terminals and make sure to run on two different ports

terminal 1:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
```

terminal 2:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001 --settings=myproject.admin_settings
```

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite Django authorization, is it difficult ?

Comment: I am currently opening the admin panel in incognito mode. But soon I want to upload the project to the hosting. I think that's when the problems will begin

Comment: Yes, I think rewriting Django authorization to do what you want is going to be difficult. Setting up the admin a a separate website with separate cookies will accomplish the same thing with less effort.